# WYSWIG Tools change based on user role and Inner Content Tool

Tags: 2sxc

Is it possible to load different options in the WYSIWIG field type. We want the ability for lower level editors to have certain options but sys admins to see more tools. You could do this with DNN editor but not sure if there is an easy configuration possible for this.

Also, what is the tool for the inner content block. When i add this "addcontentblock" to the tool options it seems to break it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no functionality to vary the toolbar by user role.

We currently believe that it's not necessary, because by default the included buttons are vary basic, so it's rarely necessary to reduce them even more.

You can of course create a custom wysiwyg control (possible but quite challenging) and implement this yourself. https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/ui242/page

Content-blocks require a (usually hidden field) right after the wysiwyg-field which will store all the references to other content-blocks. You are probably missing that. Check out the blog-app or something to see how it works.

If that field exists, the button appears automatically.

Comment: the Addcontentblock button does work, I must have had something else wrong when I was trying it. Is there a best method for cache when changing things like this, through 2sxc insights maybe? 

Is there a way of running a formula to switch the InputType, so you would change form say "string-wysiwig" to our custom one "string-wysiwig-micro" pending if the user is system admin or not since its still a string filed its just changing the type pending on the user.

Comment: You could use a custom API to find out what role the user is in, and the switching would have to happen inside your string-wysiwyg-micro to show either less or more toolbars.